# MKMapView Annotation setCoordinate crashing app

Tags: iphone, mkmapview, mkannotation

I am working on a simple GPS-like app. I created a custom object which extends MKAnnotation which also works fine. I can place it etc, but if I put this piece of code `[mpm setCoordinate:loc];` in my code, the app opens and freezes while showing the basic gray-grid (not showing any downloaded map and non of my buttons work either then)

Here is my header:

```
@interface FirstViewController : UIViewController <MKMapViewDelegate>
{
    IBOutlet MKMapView *mapView;
    MyPlaceMark *mpm;
}
-(void)locationUpdate:(CLLocation *)location;
-(void)locationError:(NSError *)error;
@end
```

And here is the piece of code where I try to update things:

```
-(void)locationUpdate:(CLLocation *)location
{
    CLLocationCoordinate2D loc = [location coordinate];
    [mpm setCoordinate:loc]; // This line messes it up.
    [mapView setCenterCoordinate:loc];
    if([mapView showsUserLocation] == NO)
         [mapView setShowsUserLocation:YES]; // This does not show my position either?
}
```

If I comment that line out, the app works fine. I need to update the annotation as it will be my marker for showing the users current location. PS: Without that line, it does center my view - so `location` is a valid/set variable.

My `viewDidLoad` looks like this:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    mapView = [[MKMapView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.bounds];
    //mapView.showsUserLocation = YES;
    [mapView setShowsUserLocation:YES];
    mapView.mapType = MKMapTypeStandard;
    mapView.delegate = self;
    CLLocationCoordinate2D location;
    MKCoordinateRegion region;
    location.latitude = -33.8;
    location.longitude = 18.6;
    MKCoordinateSpan span;
    span.latitudeDelta = 0.01;
    span.longitudeDelta = 0.01;
    region.span = span;
    region.center = location;
    [mapView setRegion:region animated:TRUE];
    [mapView regionThatFits:region];
    mpm = [[MyPlaceMark alloc] initWithCoordinate:location]; // Creating mpm
    [mapView addAnnotation:mpm]; // Adding mpm
    [self.view addSubview:mapView];
    [super viewDidLoad];
}
```

Should I re-add `mpm` after I changed it's location? Or would it just jump to its new location on the map?

So to recap the question: How can I update the custom MKAnnotation's location on my mapview?

Thank you for your time!

EDIT: I think the main reason for the crash is the fact that I do not create a `setCoordinate` method/function in my custom MKAnnotation. How would I override that but keep it same as original?

The error in log-console:

```
2011-06-09 14:42:40.377 AeroNav[3706:707] -[MyPlaceMark setCoordinate:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x19e0e0
2011-06-09 14:42:40.493 AeroNav[3706:707] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[MyPlaceMark setCoordinate:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x19e0e0'
...
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'NSException'
```

Comment: Update: I think you have to remove old annotation and add new annotation. for crash what's log in console ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`[mapView setShowsUserLocation:YES]` doesn't update the region that the map shows. You will have to implement the delegate methods `didUpdateUserLocation:` and call the `setRegion:animated:` there to move the region to user's location. Until this is called for the first time, the `userLocation` property of `MKMapView` is not set.

As for the `MKAnnotation` thing, `MKAnnotation` is a protocol. It doesn't have a default implementation. You will have to provide for all the methods and properties that you've agreed to conform to. So declare a property pretty similar to the one in the `MKAnnotation` protocol.

Comment: OMW - it now works and for the very first time shows the blue dot with circle around it. I removed a lot of code including removing the annotation :/ Haha, this works well for now. ... That `setShowsUserLocation` and `setRegion` gets called in the viewdidload as in code above... anycase, it works now after some random edits. Thanks.